# oauth login in multi-steps form is not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to implement multi-step form which involves 4 steps,these steps divided in:
     **STEP 1**
       Basic Details

**STEP 2**
Extra Details

**STEP 3**
More Details

**STEP 4**
I have social login i.e google,facebook.

Now,if user log in via google or facebook it redirected to google/faceboo page for authentication and after authenticating it redirected to redirecturl and i lost all details which was filled in last 3 steps.

So my question is how can i get details from first 3 steps and use them and store in mysql database corresponding to the logged in user.

Guys please suggest me how can i solve this problem or any other alternative solution for this problem

Comment: tried using sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions, cookies, or better yet: Put the SSO (single sign on via FB/google/etc) login first... you can fill in step 1, 2, 3 from the data you get back from the provider.

Comment: can u suggest me any tutorial link to accomplish that task

Comment: There are a ton of providers out there you can use - so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel - but it may still require custom coding. Check out http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/ for example

Comment: i can implement oauth,i was talking about storing the inputs from last 3 steps in sessions,cookies ,before user's login

Comment: Ah, look into using sessions - I'd search on how to use PHP sessions to get the idea.

Comment: i got it working i knew about oauth and session but did n't had the idea about how to approach the problem, now i've solved it finally thankyou